# выдаёт ошибку TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio

Написал код тг бота, ключевая суть кода заключается в цикле while. Если пользователь пишет слово "бот", то запускается цикл, который каждую 1 секунду присылает сообщение и если пользователь пишет слово "стоп", то бот выключает цикл. Это я смог реализовать, НО после команды стоп бот не запускает заново цикл если пользователь пишет слово "бот". попробовал сделать и выдало ошибку TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable

мой код:

```
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import BotCommand, BotCommandScopeDefault
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import asyncio
import threading as th
from threading import Thread



logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token="")

dp = Dispatcher(bot)
stop = True







@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет, {0.first_name}! если есть ко мне какие-то вопросы напишите команду /help, я вам расскажу какие у меня есть команды)".format(message.from_user))




@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def get_user_text(message):
    global stop
    if message.text == 'бот':
        while stop == True:
            stop = True
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Бот работает каждые 10 секунд")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        th = Thread(target=get_user_text(message)).start()




    elif message.text == 'стоп':
        stop = False
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "бот остановлен")

    else:
       await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "я тебя не понимаю", parse_mode='html')

    return await get_user_text()



async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Внимательнее читайте ошибка в большинстве случаев ответ прямо там

```
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import BotCommand, BotCommandScopeDefault
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import asyncio
import threading as th
from threading import Thread

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token="")

dp = Dispatcher(bot)
stop = True
bot_flag = False

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет, {0.first_name}! Если есть ко мне какие-то вопросы, напишите команду /help, я вам расскажу, какие у меня есть команды".format(message.from_user))


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def get_user_text(message):
    global stop
    global bot_flag
    if message.text == 'бот':
        bot_flag = True
        if stop == True:
            stop = False
            while stop == False:
                await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Бот работает каждые 10 секунд")
                await asyncio.sleep(10)
                if bot_flag == False:
                    stop = True
        else:
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Бот уже работает")


    elif message.text == 'стоп':
        bot_flag = False
        stop = True
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "бот остановлен")

    else:
       await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я тебя не понимаю", parse_mode='html')


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```